# Plot and table in R-studio

Tags: r

I want to make a model and plot that shows how long it takes for salmon lice to lay eggs and how the time differ between wild and farmed salmon lices.

Then I want to make a table or paragraph that uses the plot.

I tried to use Phind to make the plot. But the codes gave me two straight columns in the plot.

here is the codes:

```
model <- glm(daysPI ~ status + exp + origin + tank2 + tank, data=data, family=poisson())

library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(data, aes(x=status, y=daysPI, color=exp)) + geom_point() + 
geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="poisson"), se=FALSE) + 
labs(x="Status", y="Days to Start Laying Eggs", color="Experiment Room")`
```

Comment: So what does it have to do with Python or JS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please refer to this post to see how you can ask a good questions with a _reproducible example_ and a _specific issue to address_. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/16730940  If you can follow that guideline you are MUCH more likely to receive a meaningful response.  At present your question is very much "do this for me" rather than asking for specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `fitted()` to show model prediction instead of geom_smooth which is a different basic model. like below:

```
data%>%cbind(fitted=fitted(model))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=status, y=daysPI, color=exp, group=exp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(aes(y=fitted(model)),fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1) +#
  labs(x="Status", y="Days to Start Laying Eggs", color="Experiment Room")
```

Comment: Got the same two lines, but it looks even better, thanks! Do you know how to make a publishable table of the model afterwards? Some table codes you would recommend? I am a beginner at this.

Comment: @Sammy Did not notice you don't have `group` for summarizing. I added `, group=exp` in the `aes`. Check the results. Package `'sjPlot'`, and its `tab_model()` give you a stadard table of regression models. Also, package `'apa'` can format Outputs of Statistical Tests.

Comment: Alright, I still got the same two lines, however it got two additional lines connecting them. uncertain if that shows the difference in time between egg hatching in wild lice and farmed lice.

I will try the tables.

Comment: @Sammy You probably need to also first check your model results, using summary(model). If the `exp` factor is not significant, then the lines certainly won't differ.

Comment: Here are my exp factors: 0.0806369,  0.0457338,   1.763 and 0.077870

Should be significant.

Comment: @Sammy which one is the p value, 0.077870? If so, that is large than 0.05 and therefore not significant.

Comment: Okei, here is the summary: 

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 53.89719   28.84233   1.869
statuswild   1.94254   23.59903   0.082
exp          6.12548   24.44326   0.251
originF      4.77442   33.22119   0.144
tank2        0.08868    0.07070   1.254

Comment: @Sammy weird, you should get a table with headers like  Coefficients:  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|) for each factor. and Pr is the p value.